# How to disable/enable full text indexed in SQL Server using dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Please can somebody tell me how to disable/enable full text indexed in SQL Server using dynamic SQL?

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @db SYSNAME = DB_NAME()

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = '
USE ' + QUOTENAME(@db) + '
EXEC sys.sp_fulltext_database @action = ''' +
    CASE WHEN DATABASEPROPERTY(@db, 'IsFulltextEnabled') = 1
        THEN 'disable'
        ELSE 'enable'
    END + ''''

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

output -

```
USE [database1]
EXEC sys.sp_fulltext_database @action = 'disable'

USE [database1]
EXEC sys.sp_fulltext_database @action = 'enable'
```